# associate the PropertyEditor to a specific Controller

Tags: grails, propertyeditor

Is there a way to associate the PropertyEditor to a specific Controller.

I might want to have two PropertyEditor's for DateTime class, and want to associate them to different controllers.

or a domain class with 2 Date field, one need change 2010-12-23 to date, another need 2010-12-23 10:00:01

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to associate with a Controller. `PropertyEditorRegistrar` has only two signatures for `registerCustomEditor()`: for a whole property class, and for a property name. 
The second signature **didn't work before Grails 1.3.6**, it's a bug [GRAILS-6592](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-6592).
So

```
registry.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, 'startDate', new MyDateAddressEditor())
```

will work since Grails 1.3.6.